# how to get admob ads showing in appcelerator android app

Tags: android, firebase, admob, maps, appcelerator

Hello I am using appcelerator studio version 7.1.1.GA and am porting an iphone app to android for a client.  I tried a bunch of things but am unable to get admob ads to show up in the app and the error message I get is ==>

[WARN] :   Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
[WARN] :   Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date

I am using version 2.2.0 of the 'firebase.core' module, version 4.0.0 of the 'ti.admob' module, version 11.0.40 of ti.playservices (whatever is included with Appcelerator Studio I believe) and version 4.2.0 of the 'ti.map' module.  I am also using version 2.0.0 of the ti.googlesignin module.  Everything else the map and google signin work fine.  I tried a bunch of different things including ti.playservices, not including it and also when I had version 4.1.0 of the 'ti.admob' module installed I was getting dexer linking errors which did not seem right and when I reverted to the 4.0.0 version of 'ti.admob' the linker errors went away.

This is the last thing I need to do to release this app to the Google Play Store I have managed to get everything else is working but it would be a bummer not to have ads in the app.  I really don't want to disappoint my client.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue is. It is real simple I just had to pass the ad unit id in as the publisher id in Admob.createView({ publisherId: 'ad unit id', ... }); Talk about confusing!